# Calculate $E(X \cdot Y)$ of the given density

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, discrete-mathematics

> $X,Y$ are two random variables with density function
>
> $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{4}{3}-\frac{1}{3}x-\frac{1}{3}y&\mbox{if
> }1<x<2, 0<y<2 \\  0&\mbox{else}\end{cases}$$
>
> It is known that $E(X) = \frac{13}{9}$ and $E(Y) = \frac{7}{9}. \;\;\;\;$ Calculate $E(XY)$

I like to know how this is done correctly because I'm pretty sure it will be a part of the exam I write soon?

$$E(XY) = \int_{1}^{2} \int_{0}^{2}xy \cdot f(x,y)\, dy \;dx$$

Now we should firstly calculate $$F_Y(y) = \int_{0}^{2} y \cdot f(x,y) \, dy = \int_{0}^{2} \frac{4}{3}y-\frac{1}{3}xy-\frac{1}{3}y^2 \, dy = 2-\frac{2}{3}x$$

Then we have that $$E(XY)=\int_{1}^{2}x\cdot F_Y(y)\;dx = \int_{1}^{2}2x-\frac{2}{3}x^2\;dx = \frac{13}{9}$$

Comment: Your method is correct, but I believe you have made a mistake in your calculations. Please check your book for the definition of $F_Y$ to check whether that coincides with what you used it for here.

Comment: It should be $F_Y(x)=\frac{2}{9}(8 - 3 x)$ and then $E[XY]=\frac{10}{9}$.

Comment: @dromastyx How do you know $F_Y(x) = \frac{2}{9}(8-3x)$?

Comment: @roblind The integral is $[2y^2/3-xy^2/6-y^3/9]_0^2=8/3-2x/3-8/9=16/9-2x/3=\frac{2}{9}(8-3x)$.

Comment: The notation $F_Y$ to denote this integral is a rather bad choice since $F_Y$ usually denotes the CDF of $Y$.

Comment: @Did What about $f_Y$? Or would that be even worse since we have $f(x,y)$ here? Is there any common notation for it?

Comment: As bad. No common notation.